# Java: Dijkstra's Algorithm - change number of edges using random edges

Tags: java, graph, dijkstra

I have a program that implements Dijkstra's algorithm for graphs. I am to create a graph with 10 vertices and 30 random edges. However, I do not know how to get exactly 30 edges. I have the code, but I just can't seem to find where I need to change so that I get 30 edges each time I run the code. I know this is simple, but I had to change the code from reading in a file with the edges to randomly assigning them. Right now I am getting 16 edges. Any assistance in creating my graph with exactly 30 edges would be great!

Here is the code:

Graph class:

```
package TestGraphs;

import TestGraphs.Vertex;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Graph {

public Vertex[] vertex;
public double[] centerVert;
public double[][] weight; // weight[i][j] >= 0.0 indicates an edge
public double center;
public int centerV;

public Graph(int numVertices) {
    vertex = new Vertex[numVertices];
    weight = new double[numVertices][numVertices];
    centerVert = new double[numVertices];
    for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numVertices; j++) {
            weight[i][j] = -1.0; // no edge
        }
    }
}

public void createAdjacencyLists() {
    for (int i = 0; i < vertex.length; i++) {
        vertex[i].neighbors = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
        for (int j = 0; j < vertex.length; j++) {
            if (j != i && weight[i][j] > 0.0) {
                vertex[i].neighbors.add(vertex[j]);
            }
        }

    }
}

public void printGraph() {
    System.out.println("Vertices:");
    for (int i = 0; i < vertex.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + ": " + vertex[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("Edges:");
    for (int i = 0; i < vertex.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(vertex[i] + " neighbors:");
        for (int j = 0; j < vertex.length; j++) {
            if (j != i && weight[i][j] > 0.0) {
                System.out.print(" " + vertex[j] + "w:" + String.format("%.2f", weight[i][j]));
                centerVert[i] = weight[i][j] + centerVert[j];
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    for (int k = 1; k < vertex.length; k++) {
        center = centerVert[0];
        if (center > centerVert[k]) {
            centerV = k;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The center vertex is " + vertex[centerV]);
}

ArrayList<Vertex> breadthFirstSearch(Vertex source) {

    ArrayList<Vertex> queue = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
    ArrayList<Vertex> visited = new ArrayList<Vertex>();

    // mark all vertices as not visited:
    for (int i = 0; i < vertex.length; i++) {
        vertex[i].visited = false;
    }
    source.visited = true;
    queue.add(source);
    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        Vertex head = queue.remove(0);
        visited.add(head);
        for (Iterator<Vertex> iter = head.neighbors.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
            Vertex neighbor = iter.next();
            if (!neighbor.visited) {
                neighbor.visited = true;
                queue.add(neighbor);
            }
        }
    }

    return visited;
}

// Dijkstra's algorithm:
public void dijkstra(Vertex source) {
    ArrayList<Vertex> VminusS = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
    for (int i = 0; i < vertex.length; i++) {
        vertex[i].d = Double.MAX_VALUE; // + infinity
        vertex[i].pred = null;
        VminusS.add(vertex[i]);
    }
    source.d = 0.0;
    while (!VminusS.isEmpty()) {
        Vertex smallestDVertex = null;
        for (Iterator<Vertex> iter = VminusS.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
            Vertex current = iter.next();
            if (smallestDVertex == null || current.d < smallestDVertex.d) {
                smallestDVertex = current;
            }
        }
        for (Iterator<Vertex> iter = smallestDVertex.neighbors.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
            Vertex neighbor = iter.next();
            double edgeWt = weight[smallestDVertex.index][neighbor.index];
            if (smallestDVertex.d + edgeWt < neighbor.d) {
                neighbor.d = smallestDVertex.d + edgeWt;
                neighbor.pred = smallestDVertex;
            }
        }
        VminusS.remove(smallestDVertex);
    }
    System.out.println("Dijsktra's algorithm finished for source vertex " + source);
}

public void printShortestPath(Vertex destination, Vertex source) {
    //ArrayList<Vertex> path = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
    System.out.print("The shortest path from " + source + " to " + destination + " is: ");
    Vertex cur = destination;
    while (cur != null) {
        System.out.print(cur + " -> ");
        //path.add(0, cur);
        cur = cur.pred;
    }
    //System.out.println();
}
}
```

Vertex Class:

```
package TestGraphs;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Vertex {
public String name;
public int x, y;
public boolean visited;
public double d; // used by Dijkstra's alg
public Vertex pred; // used by Dijkstra's alg
public int index;

// used for adjacency list representation:
ArrayList<Vertex> neighbors;

public Vertex(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String toString() {
    return "(" + x + "," + y + ")";
}
}
```

Test Class:
    package TestGraphs;

```
import TestGraphs.Vertex;
import java.util.Random;

public class TestGraphs {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static double distance(double x0, double y0, double x1, double y1) {
    return Math.sqrt((x1 - x0) * (x1 - x0) + (y1 - y0) * (y1 - y0));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    Random r = new Random();
    int source;
    int numVertices = 10;

    Graph g = new Graph(numVertices);
    for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++) {
        g.vertex[i] = new Vertex("Vertex " + i);
        g.vertex[i].x = r.nextInt(10);
        g.vertex[i].y = r.nextInt(10);
        g.vertex[i].index = i;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++) {
        for (int s = 0; s < 2; s++) {
            int n = r.nextInt(numVertices);
            while (n == i) {
                n = r.nextInt(numVertices);
            }
            g.weight[i][n] = g.weight[n][i]
                    = distance(g.vertex[i].x, g.vertex[i].y, g.vertex[n].x, g.vertex[n].y);
        }
    }

//        // find nearest neighbors:
//        for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++) {
//            double lowestD = Double.MAX_VALUE;
//            int nearestNeighbor = 0;
//            for (int j = 0; j < numVertices; j++) {
//                if (i != j) {
//                    double d = distance(g.vertex[i].x, g.vertex[i].y,
//                            g.vertex[j].x, g.vertex[j].y);
//                    if (d < lowestD) {
//                        nearestNeighbor = j;
//                        lowestD = d;
//                    }
//                }
//            }
//            // add edge between i and nearestneighbor;
//            System.out.println(g.vertex[i] + " has nearest neighbor " + g.vertex[nearestNeighbor]);
//            g.weight[i][nearestNeighbor] = lowestD;
//        }
    g.createAdjacencyLists();
    g.printGraph();
    g.dijkstra(g.vertex[0]);
    System.out.println("vertex d values (after running Dijsktra's algorithm):");
    for (int i = 0; i < g.vertex.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(g.vertex[i] + " d: " + String.format("%.2f", g.vertex[i].d));
    }
    System.out.println();

    // test some shortest paths:
    source = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++) {
        g.printShortestPath(g.vertex[i], g.vertex[source]);
        System.out.println("(distance = " + String.format("%.2f", g.vertex[i].d) + ")");
    }


    source = 5;
    //System.out.println("BFS returns: " + g.breadthFirstSearch(g.vertex[0]));
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 30; ++i) {
    int startVertex, endVertex;
    do {
        startVertex = random.nextInt(graphSize);
        endVertex = random.nextInt(graphSize);
    while (startVertex == endVertex) || graph.containsEdge(startVertex, endVertex);
    graph.addEdge(startVertex, endVertex);
}
```

This sample contains some pseudocode, but the idea should be clear.